# Why does MongoDB store coordinates as longitude first?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, latitude-longitude

I have experienced and seen many Geo query errors in MongoDB due to misplace latitude and longitude. MongoDB specifies the format to be Longitude first contrary to normal usage of Latitude first. However I can't find any resaon or explanation on why?

So, my question is:

Is there any practical implications or benefits using longitude first?

Comment: It's the same order as supported by the GeoJSON spec.

Comment: There is also no "normal usage", according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18721489/98057). WSG84 also uses long, lat.

Comment: Longitude is the *x* axis, latitude the *y* axis. Generally the order is always x, y.